Windows Network Diagnostics. DNS PROBE FINISHED NXDOMAIN
[This site can't be reached Check if there is a typo in my.acumen.edu.au. If spelling is correct, try runningthe sub domain hosted on AWS and the domain is on crazydomain, is there any IP error? or dns settings mapping error? This issue is occasionally arise on few members who are using or working on this link. I don't know what will be the issue. Please help me to find the actual error.


The domain resolves just fine. What problem you have on a client is impossible for us to debug.

How to debung? like they told me to contact to AWS support

Debugging problems that occur only in some places are hard... Basically figure out the difference between where it works and where it doesn't, and look into the configuration differences.

@vidarlo Whenever a student, trainee, or administrator engages with this sub-domain "my.example.edu.au", they may encounter an error that takes approximately 2 minutes to resolve. Upon contacting domain support, I was informed that the issue does not originate from their end but rather from the hosting provider, which operates on AWS. It is possible that this error arises due to an alias within the subdomain structure. that's how they told me

please help me in a proper answer

We can't really help you with intermittent problems on a client device.

The error can actually mean a host of different things depending on circumstances.
Most Windows clients get their DNS settings from the routers DHCP server and will most likely just pass along your ISP's providers DNS resolver.
But let's say you (or somebody else) have configured a DNS resolver on your local network then we need to find out if your machine is aware of the DNS resolver and if the DNS resolver is setup properly.
I will start with the Windows client and work my way out on the local network.
For reference: I will use Bind9 DNS resolver as reference when I refer to a local DNS server.
1) Inproper/missing DNS configuration on Windows client
If you are connected with ethernet cable then go to:
Start -> Settings -> Network & Internet -> Ethernet.
Check if the page says something about "IPv4 DNS server".
It can say DNS is assigned by DHCP.
If it is assigned by DHCP, then you can test if DHCP setting is wrong by manually assign it to Google Public DNS instead by editing the DNS configuration to the ip addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.
There are other public DNS servers, such as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1 & 1.0.0.1) and OpenDNS (208.67.222.222 & 208.67.220.220) and quite few other providers.
If you can reach the site using any of the DNS resolvers mentioned above, then there is something wrong with your normal DNS resolver.
2) Is the local DNS server working?
You can test if your local DNS server is working by starting the console by either lauching cmd or using PowerShell.
To test if the resolver is working write nslookup google.com ip.of.dns.server.
Try also for the domain you have troubles with by replacing google.com with your domain.
It may be querying google.com is allowed, but your domain is not allowed or do not exist.
Therefore we have to look at how the resolver is configured.
3) Does your local DNS server listen to traffic on IPv4?
You can skip this part if you got an answer in item 2 above.
The default configuration of bind9 DNS resolver will only listen to traffic on IPv6 ... and maybe any traffic on localhost.
Therefore you need to add the following configuration to the options section:
listen-on { server.lan.ip.adress; };

The section is usually found in at the path: /etc/bind/named.conf.options
4) Does you local DNS server permit lookup from clients in your LAN subnet?
You can skip this part if you got an answer in item 2 above.
We use Access Control Lists (ACLs) to define who is allowed to query the DNS server.
Assuming your LAN is on the IPv4 subnet 192.168.0.0/24 and the IPv6 subnet for your LAN is 2001:db8:cafe:beef::/64, then I would usually define ACL with the following content:
acl trusted-net {
  localhost;
  localnet;
  192.168.0.0/24;
  2001:db8:cafe:beef::/64;
};

Define this section before the beginning of options { ... }; section.
We can then tell the DNS server to permit query and recursive querying and cached lookup using the following entries in the options section:
# Forward any queries to Google Public DNS in 
# case the DNS record in question is not 
# hosted by the DNS server.

forwarders {
  8.8.8.8;
  8.8.4.4;
};

# Allow clients to lookup any records the 
# DNS server is authoritative for.

allow-query { trusted-net; };

# Allow the client to ask the DNS server 
# to forward the request to whatever server 
# is responsible for the domain name in question.

# Note: Do NOT use 'any' as a value, since 
# it can be used to abuse your DNS server for 
# denial-of-service attacks. 

allow-recursion { trusted-net; };

# Who can lookup in DNS servers cache for the DNS record. 
# It is faster than to forward the query every time you 
# need to access the same DNS record at remote server.

# Note: Do NOT use 'any' as a value, since 
# it can be used to abuse your DNS server for 
# denial-of-service attacks. 

allow-query-cache { trusted-net; };

5) Does the DNS record belong to a locally hosted domain?
I am assuming you have defined a zone the contains your locally hosted domain like for instance: lan.example.com.
However you may have enabled dnssec verification for all dns lookups so if you haven't created relevant dnssec records for your domain then the resolver will return NXDOMAIN because it cannot verify that your DNS server is actually allowed to reply with resource records for your local domain.
It may also be that you have a SAMBA Active Directory Domain Controller and is therefore using bind9_dlz or hosting it using SAMBA_INTERNAL DNS backend.
Whatever the case is, it is not possible to generate DNSSEC records for those domains, due to not supported by SAMBA at current time.
This means you have two options:

Disable DNSSEC verification (not desirable).
Make an exemption for your local LAN domain.

The way you make an exemption for the domain: lan.example.com is by adding the following to the options section:
validate-except {
  "lan.example.com";
};

... and for whatever change you make Bind9 configuration, please remember to reload or restart the DNS server.
Those are the questions I have had when troubleshooting my DNS server.
I do not know if there are other situations that can generate the NXDOMAIN response.

OK Will check it once

@MohdZaheer: Try look at my answer now. They will get you started at least on what is wrong.

Definitely @Lasse Michael Mølgaard I will try implement this points which you have shared with me. Truly appreciated.
